# MongoDB find and update and validate empty fields from body

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to check if the following values are not empty before I update the fields.
So I build the following way but don't retrieve me  the msg errors and don't let me uptade the profile user.

```
router.post("/profileEdit/:id", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
  let errors = [];
  if (!req.body.firstName) {
    errors.push({ text: "Please add your first name" });
  }
  if (!req.body.lastName) {
    errors.push({ text: "Please add your last name" });
  }
  if (!req.body.username) {
    errors.push({ text: "Please add your username" });
  }
  if (!req.body.email) {
    errors.push({ text: "Please add you email" });
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.render("users/profileEdit", {
      errors: errors,
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email
    });
  } else {
    User.updateOne(
      { _id: id },
      {
        $set: {
          firstName: req.body.firstName,
          lastName: req.body.lastName,
          username: req.body.username,
          email: req.body.email
        }
      }
    ).then(user => {
      req.flash("success_msg", "Profile Updated");
      res.redirect("/users/profile/" + id);
    });
  }
});
```

How can I validate if the req.body for each field is empty or not? And after this validation, I need to update the info inside mongodb.

Comment: so what's not working?

Comment: @Carlos Orelhas : Though you can do it using js but in node.js world it's quiet common to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi , look into it as it might help you..

Comment: @technophyle The way I show above won't work.. can't validate the fields

Comment: the validation code looks fine to me. maybe it's a problem with your `profileEdit` template.

Comment: Both work fine, but I think I need to find first the id and after this do the validation.. because of this way show me multiple lines inside the profileEdit

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the following:

Before the else, I just need to find the _id:id, this way and since the fields above are empty, the app will return the same page with the fields filled.

```
router.post("/profileEdit/:id", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
  let errors = [];

  if (!req.body.firstName) {
    errors.push({ text: "Please add your first name" });
  }
  if (!req.body.lastName) {
    errors.push({ text: "Please add your last name" });
  }
  if (!req.body.username) {
    errors.push({ text: "Please add your username" });
  }
  if (!req.body.email) {
    errors.push({ text: "Please add you email" });
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    User.find(
      { _id: id },
      {
        firstName: 1,
        lastName: 1,
        username: 1,
        email: 1,
        password: 1,
        _id: { $elemMatch: { _id: id } },
        date: 1
      }
    ).then(user => {
      res.render("users/profileEdit", {
        user: user
      });
    });
  } else {
    User.updateOne(
      { _id: id },
      {
        $set: {
          firstName: req.body.firstName,
          lastName: req.body.lastName,
          username: req.body.username,
          email: req.body.email
        }
      }
    ).then(user => {
      req.flash("success_msg", "Profile Updated");
      res.redirect("/users/profile/" + id);
    });
  }
});
```